# How to approach loop with increasing variable name in R

Tags: r, for-loop

My dataset is currently a set of answers to twenty questions with 300 observations.

Each of the questions are labled q1, q2, q3, etc.

Each observation gives a 1 to 10 response.

The code below is what I have.  What I want is for the q1 to change when the counter changes in R.

```
totaltenq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$tenq1)
totalnineq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$nineq1)
totaleightq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$eightq1)
totalsevenq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$sevenq1)
totalsixq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$sixq1)
totalfiveq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$fiveq1)
totalfourq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$fourq1)
totalthreeq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$threeq1)
totaltwoq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$twoq1)
totaloneq1 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$oneq1)

totaltenq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$tenq2)
totalnineq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$nineq2)
totaleightq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$eightq2)
totalsevenq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$sevenq2)
totalsixq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$sixq2)
totalfiveq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$fiveq2)
totalfourq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$fourq2)
totalthreeq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$threeq2)
totaltwoq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$twoq2)
totaloneq2 <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$oneq2)
```

I would like to have code that is

```
count = 20

for (i in 1:count){
totaltenq(i) <- sum(UpdatedQualtrix$tenq(i)
totalninq(I) <- sum(UpdatedQuatlrix$nineq(I)
etc
}
```

That way, when I do it again in the future, I can tell R how many questions it has the next time and it will change it.  That way I don't have 10,000 lines of code from copying and pasting my code 20 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need any loops at all. It just all depends on how you want to store those value. I'm a big fan of not having more variables than necessary.

Here's some sample data. I'll just make 10 rows (observations) with values 1-5.

```
set.seed(15)
Q<-3
numbs<-c("one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten")
qs<-paste0("q",1:Q)
qnumbs <- outer(numbs, qs, paste0)

UpdatedQualtrix <-data.frame(ID=1:10, 
    matrix(sample(1:5, 10*length(numbs)*Q, replace=T), nrow=10))
colnames(UpdatedQualtrix) <- c("ID",qnumbs)
```

Now I can sum up each of the columns with

```
( Qsums<-colSums(UpdatedQualtrix[, qnumbs]) )

# oneq1   twoq1 threeq1  fourq1  fiveq1   sixq1 sevenq1 eightq1  nineq1   tenq1 
#    37      35      29      26      32      39      40      33      40      26 
# oneq2   twoq2 threeq2  fourq2  fiveq2   sixq2 sevenq2 eightq2  nineq2   tenq2 
#    37      31      19      29      25      38      36      35      28      27 
# oneq3   twoq3 threeq3  fourq3  fiveq3   sixq3 sevenq3 eightq3  nineq3   tenq3 
#    37      30      31      31      24      31      29      31      25      41
```

And if we want the totals per question we can do

```
sapply(qs, function(a, b) sum(Qsums[paste0(b,a)]), b=numbs)

#  q1  q2  q3 
# 337 305 310
```

Or if we want the counts per response we can do

```
sapply(numbs, function(a, b) sum(Qsums[paste0(a,b)]), b=qs)

#   one   two three  four  five   six seven eight  nine   ten 
#   111    96    79    86    81   108   105    99    93    94
```

You might want to also consider melting your data since it's so structured. You can use the `reshape2` library to help. You can do

```
require(reshape2)

mm <- melt(UpdatedQualtrix, id.vars="ID")
mm <- cbind(mm[,-2], colsplit(mm$variable, "q", c("resp","q")))
mm$resp <- factor(mm$resp, levels=numbs)
```

to turn your data into a "tall" format so each value has it's own row with a column for ID, value, response and question.

```
str(mm)

# 'data.frame': 300 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ ID   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ value: int  4 1 5 4 2 5 5 2 4 5 ...
#  $ resp : Factor w/ 10 levels "one","two","three",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ q    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

And then we can more easily do other calculations. Of you want the total scores by question, you could do

```
aggregate(value~q, mm, sum)
#   q value
# 1 1   337
# 2 2   305
# 3 3   310
```

If you wanted the average value for each question/response you could do

```
with(mm, tapply(value, list(q,resp), mean))
#   one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
# 1 3.7 3.5   2.9  2.6  3.2 3.9   4.0   3.3  4.0 2.6
# 2 3.7 3.1   1.9  2.9  2.5 3.8   3.6   3.5  2.8 2.7
# 3 3.7 3.0   3.1  3.1  2.4 3.1   2.9   3.1  2.5 4.1
```